# how to Replace all characters A and c from input to Z and e respectively

Tags: linux, shell, unix

without using sed or awk

I tried this command to solve this problem

tr Ac Ze

but this command doesn't work
Does any help, please?

Comment: `echo ABc | tr Ac Ze` works here just fine. Using Linux as tagged.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details.Your problem description "this command doesn't work" is not sufficient. Please show the input you use and the output or error message you actually get and the output you expect to get. Do you enter the command shown in the question and type the input? Or how do you feed the input into the command?

Comment: @pacifiqzeirakoze : That part of the pipe you posted, looks fine. Please provide a complete command which we can reproduce, and tell us which output you get, as opposed to which output you expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` command:

- **g**: Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.
- **s**: stand for substitute

```
$ -> echo Aca | sed 's/A/Z/g; s/c/e/g'
Zea
```

Or just use `tr` command as said @James

```
$ -> echo Aca | tr Ac Ze
Zea
```

**Another example**:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Insert word: " word
echo $word | tr Ac Ze
```

**Result**:

```
Insert word: Aca
Zea
```

**Or**:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Insert word: " word
echo $word | sed 's/A/Z/g; s/c/e/g'
```

**Aditional info**:

- **tr**

```
$ -> whatis tr
tr (1)               - translate or delete characters
```

- **sed**

```
$ -> whatis sed
sed (1)              - stream editor for filtering and transforming text
```